# Get sensor values while main thread is paused

Tags: android, android-sensors, onpause, sensormanager

Is there a way to get values from a sensor while the main thred is paused?

GOAL: I need to register the light sensor, the main thread must wait 10 seconds and then i must get an average value after these 10 seconds.

PROBLEM: I must wait in the main thread, so if i do a while or a sleep, the sensor doesn't get any value

WHAT I TRIED: I tried to register the sensor in another thread or asynctask, but nothing happened if i pause the main thread for 10 seconds (i tried with a sleep, with an handler, with a while and with a join). A user suggested me to use a Handler and the onPause/onResume. My actual code is this, but i still don't get anything while the main thread is waiting:

```
public class MyActivity
{
    private Lux light; //Lux implements SensorEventListener
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listeners);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        light=new Lux();
        onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(light, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT));
        light.getAverage();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(light, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        Handler h=new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(myTask, 10000);
    }

    private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            onResume();
        }
    };
}
```

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this way. it was simpler that i thought.

```
SensorManager mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

HandlerThread mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("sensorThread");

mHandlerThread.start();

Handler handler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());

mSensorMgr.registerListener(this, mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

onPause/onResume are not intended for calling by user. They must be called only by your system.

`EventListener`'s methods are called by the system in main thread, so if you stop it by any means they just won't get called.

in your `onCreate`, not in `onPause` post a runnable, which will process recorded data.

Although it is better to use started service for your needs.

Comment: So i need a runnable in the oncreate to do what exactly? I'm sorry, but i started using android  the last month.